# How to control wether or not my app will stop any iPod music playing?

Tags: iphone

When my app launches, there are rumors that I can decide if any currently playing music is stopped or not.

My goal is to use Audio Queue Services, because I believe that's the most powerful audio technology in iPhone OS.

So, could I really decide that when my app launches? How? Which one of the many audio technologies on the iPhone OS is responsible for managing this?

Comment: You want an app to control weather?  Wow, I know Objective C and iPhone are powerful, but I don't think there's an app for that.  And what does weather have to do with playing music?  Please clarify.

Comment: The title of my questions says "wether", does it? There's an device for that: Glasses.

Comment: wether is a male sheep or goat.  Maybe you meant "whether"?  The device for that is a dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the class MPMusicPlayerController and the class method +iPodMusicPlayer

Comment: [[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] pause];  // pauses the music